# OnScrollListener in gridview in a homescreen widget, is it possible?

Tags: android, widget, homescreen, onscroll

I have a homescreen widget (android > 4.0) with a gridview and show some pictures within. And I want to make some additional views (imageview with icons or anything else) visible on scrolling this grid.

So if the user scolls through the grid, little icons within every picture is gonna be visible.
Is that possible?

I searched for something like setOnScrollListener on RemoteViews, but I didn't find anything nor a getParent to access the grid from within the griditem.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need an `OnScrollListener` for this. `GridView` already knows how to scroll and already knows how to populate additional cells in the grid based upon that scrolling. Simply provide your data to the `GridView`  (in this case, via a `RemoteViewsFactory`).

Comment: Yeah ok, I know that.Sorry, but you misunderstand me. The icons are hidden and just in case of scrolling they should be visible, just for a couple of moments.

Comment: @silversmurf: You have no way of using `OnScrollListener` with `RemoteViews`.

Comment: Ok, thats what I wanna know.
I was not sure, but I thought so.

Comment: i tried alot too and i came to the same conclusion that it isn't possible at the moment.